# Open Flash Chart : Where is the CSS?

Tags: open-flash-chart

I'm using Open Flash Chart to display some graphical data in my web page.  I would like to change the appearance of the Graph now.  I want to change the background color of the graph.  I could not find any CSS file in the download. Where should I change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using PHP, you can set the background colo**u**r (note the UK spelling!) as follows:

```
$chart = new open_flash_chart();
$chart->set_title( "my chart" );
$chart->add_element( $bar );
$chart->set_bg_colour( '#FFFFFF' );
```

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/background.php

Alternatively, if you're fiddling with the raw JSON, set the `bg_colour` element at the top level:

```
{
  "elements": [
    { "type": "bar", "values": [ 1, 2, 3 ] } 
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "my chart" 
  },
  "bg_colour": "#FFFFFF" 
}
```